# cakephp relation habtm condition

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two model News and Category. And they have habtm relation. I want to retrieve news that have a category special conditions. Like

```
$this->News->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Category.id' => 2)));

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Category.id' in 'where clause'.
```

I know this column not exist in News table but in news_categories they have a habtm relation. I need to know correct using CakePHP orm to retrieve this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is create a join table and then bind is as a hasOne temporarily.

```
$this->News->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('CategoriesNews')));
$this->News->find('all', array('fields' => array('News.*'),
    'conditions'=>array('CategoriesNews.category_id'=>2))
);
```